# A text editor which allows configuration of text to select when it is double clicked

Tags: ide, text-editor

From my experience, most text editors will, when double clicking a block of text, break the selected text by dashed lines but not for underscores.

E.g:

Double click the word 'text' of this sentence with **underscores**:

`this_text_block`

Double click the word 'text' of this sentence with **dashes**:

this-`text`-block

However, in different situations I have different needs. For example, when swapping between serverside code, html and javascript I often would like to vary the way text is selected.

**Is there a text editor that allows such a distinction? Possibly one that switches depending on the type of code I am writing?**